# Changing an Image in CSS media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am a total amateur

The idea is media query changes images.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  <<<large #sporter1 {
    display: block
  }
  #sporter2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #sportertable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #sportertable2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #target1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #target2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #targettable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #targettable2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tactical1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tactical2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tacticaltable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tacticaltable2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  <<<small **#sporter1 {
    display: none;
  }
  <- This line not working** #sporter2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #sportertable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #sportertable2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #target1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #target2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #targettable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #targettable2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tactical1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tactical2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tacticaltable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tacticaltable2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contours">
  <div id="sporter1"><img src="images/a sporter barrel diagram lg.png" width="600"></div>
  <div id="sportertable1">
    <img src="images/sporter barrel table lg.png" width="600">
  </div>
  <div id="sporter2"><img src="images/sporter barrel diagram.png" width="430"></div>
  <div id="sportertable2"><img src="images/sporter barrel table.png" width="430"></div>
  Dimensions are in inches
</div>
```

The problem is, everything works perfect, except the very first image does not "switch off", ever.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: "everything works perfect, except…" actually means that _not_ everything works perfectly.

Comment: It seems to be working (when you remove these "comments"): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLf7p0gr/)

Comment: (when you remove these "comments") ???

Comment: (when you remove these "comments") ??

What "comments" are you referring to?

Comment: @XO I mean `<<<large`, `<<<small`, `<- This line not working**` etc.

Comment: You might be interested in the `srcset` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: just remove `<<<large` from code and add semicolon after block

Comment: THANK YOU! It works perfecto now!

Answer (score 0):

You hav to remove these comments:

- <<

  <<

  <- This line not working**

That's not a proper way to comment code in CSS. Use `/* */` marks for commenting.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
  #sporter1 {
    display: block
  }
  #sporter2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #sportertable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #sportertable2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #target1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #target2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #targettable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #targettable2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tactical1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tactical2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tacticaltable1 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tacticaltable2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #sporter1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #sporter2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #sportertable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #sportertable2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #target1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #target2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #targettable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #targettable2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tactical1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tactical2 {
    display: block;
  }
  #tacticaltable1 {
    display: none;
  }
  #tacticaltable2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contours">
  <div id="sporter1"><img src="images/a sporter barrel diagram lg.png" width="600"></div>
  <div id="sportertable1">
    <img src="images/sporter barrel table lg.png" width="600">
  </div>
  <div id="sporter2"><img src="images/sporter barrel diagram.png" width="430"></div>
  <div id="sportertable2"><img src="images/sporter barrel table.png" width="430"></div>
  Dimensions are in inches
</div>
```